# Next.js with Auth0 (using Passport.js) on Serverless Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, auth0, next.js

Usually authentication isn't a big deal with auth0 and Lock.js, but it's a little tricky with Next.js and SSR. I decided to try passport.js based on a tutorial I found ([nextjs-passport](https://github.com/auth0-blog/nextjs-passport)).

I want to deploy this to Firebase, so I don't have an express server available. Passport should work with the custom callback as well, but I'm only getting a blank page and no errors.

Anyone had more luck implementing Auth0 authentication with the latest Next.js?

/pages/login.js

```js
import React from 'react'

export default () => (
  <form action='/api/login' method='post'>
    <div className='field'>
      <p className='control has-icons-left has-icons-right'>
        <input className='input' name='email' type='email' placeholder='Email' />
      </p>
    </div>
    <div className='field'>
      <p className='control has-icons-left'>
        <input className='input' name='password' type='password' placeholder='Password' />
      </p>
    </div>
    <div className='field'>
      <p className='control'>
        <input type='submit' className='button is-success' />
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
)
```

/pages/api/login.js

```js
import passport from 'passport'
import Cors from 'micro-cors'

const cors = Cors({
  allowedMethods: ['POST', 'HEAD']
})

function Login (req, res, next) {
  return passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    scope: 'openid email profile',
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true,
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }, function (err, user, info) {
    console.log(err, user, info)
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login') }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err) }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username)
    })
  })(req, res, next)
}

export default cors(Login)
```

Comment: And you're not getting any errors? Can you check if you are getting a token in the network tab of your inspector?

Comment: Also did you look at this https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial/

Comment: No errors unfortunately. The GitHub repo is based on the tutorial. The issue remains that they use an express server which I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you want to use Nextjs on Now V2 so that it is serverless. If that is not the case, my answer probably won't help you.

> I just made a [minimal repo for Auth0 and Nextjs serverless.](https://github.com/awb305/Auth0-Nextjs-Serverless)

You were on the right track realizing that [Next.js Authentication Tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial/) uses express to extend the Nextjs server, but since we are in serverless world the authentication needs to be abstracted to an api. It looks like you started that, but you didn't put a full express server in the api. In my repo, my auth lambda is ./auth/auth.js. For the above repo, the user data is called in the HOC located in ./utils/withAuth.js.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I had a look at the repo and it's definitely going in the right direction. But pulling an entire express server into a serverless function isn't really the point of serverless functions. I'll continue to dig in to the middleware and see if I can substitute that somehow. Since it's just req/res, there must be a way.

Comment: I see what you mean it's a server deployed on a serverless function, which seems a little backwards. However, I believe the server is necessary for its middleware. You are using express to manipulate the req and res object. As for routing between your pages that will still be handled by Nextjs from the pages folder. Guillermo Rauch actually talks about how people make the mistake of deploying a server to a serverless function in his interview [fullstackradio.com/112](http://www.fullstackradio.com/112). But, he also talks about how express should be used if you want to utilize its middleware.